# Save Accents in MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, diacritics

I'm trying to save French accents in my database, but they aren't saved like they should in the DB.
For example, a "é" is saved as "Ã©".
I've tried to set my files to "Unicode (utf-8)", the fields in the DB are "utf8_general_ci" as well as the DB itself.
When I look at my data posted through AJAX with Firebug, I see the accent passed as "é", so it's correct.
Thanks and let me know you need more info!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Personally I solved the same issue by adding after the **MySQL connection code**:

```
mysql_set_charset("utf8");
```

or for mysqli:

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

or the mysqli OOP equivalent:

```
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
```

And sometimes you'll have to define the **main php charset** by adding this code:

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

On the client HTML side you have to add the following header data :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

In order to use JSON AJAX results (e.g. by using jQuery), you should define the header by adding :

```
header("Content-type: application/json;charset=utf8");
json_encode(
     some_data
);
```

This should do the trick

Comment: And, if you will use `PDO`, try this: `$db = new PDO("database", "username", "pass", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'))`

Comment: Just comment that, the function `mysqli_set_charset("utf8")`, needs two parameters, the connection and the charset, so it ends like `mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")`.

Answer (score 6):

The best bet is that your database connection is not UTF-8 encoded - it is usually ISO-8859-1 by default.

Try sending a query

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

after making the connection.

Comment: I was using PHP and the shell_exec command to import an sql file, and this  solution was the only one that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
```

Answer (score 4):

if you use PDO, you must instanciate like that :

```
new \PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$schema", $username, $password, array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8') );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use UTF8:

Set a meta in your

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
```

When you connect to your mySQL DB, force encoding so you DONT have to play with your mysql settings

```
$conn = mysql_connect('server', 'user', 'password') or die('Could not connect to mysql server.');
mysql_select_db('mydb') or die('Could not select database.');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$conn); //THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
```

If you use AJAX, set you encoding like this:

```
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode.html:

> Client applications that need to
>   communicate with the server using
>   Unicode should set the client
>   character set accordingly; for
>   example, by issuing a SET NAMES 'utf8'
>   statement. ucs2 cannot be used as a
>   client character set, which means that
>   it does not work for SET NAMES or SET
>   CHARACTER SET. (See Section 9.1.4,
>   “Connection Character Sets and
>   Collations”.)

Further to that:

> if you get data via php from your
>   mysql-db (everything utf-8)  but still
>   get '?' for some special characters in
>   your browser  (),  try this:
>
> after mysql_connect() , and
>   mysql_select_db() add this lines: 
>   mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
>
> worked for me. i tried first with the
>   utf8_encode, but this only worked for
>   äüöéè...  and so on, but not for
>   kyrillic and other chars.

Answer (score 0):

You need to a) make sure your tables are using a character encoding that can encode such characters (UTF-8 tends to be the go-to encoding these days) and b) make sure that your form submissions are being sent to the database in the same character encoding.  You do this by saving your HTML/PHP/whatever files as UTF-8, and by including a meta tag in the head that tells the browser to use UTF-8 encoding.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Oh, and don't forget C, when connecting to the database, make sure you're actually using the correct character set by executing a SET NAMES charset=utf8 (might not be the correct syntax, I'll have to look up what it should be, but it will be along those lines)

Answer (score 0):

PHP(.net) advises against setting charsets after connecting using a query like SET NAMES utf8 because your functionality for escaping data inside MySQL statements might not work as intended.

Do not use SET NAMES utf8 but use the appropriate ..._set_charset() function (or method) instead, in case you are using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a working solution for me :

Run this mysql command

```
show variables like 'char%';
```

Here you have many variables : "character_set_server", "character_set_system" etc.

In my case I have "Ã©" for "é" in database and I want to show "é" on my website.

To work I have to change "character_set_server" value from "utf8mb4" to "latin1".

All my correct value are :

[image]

And other values are :

[image]

With theses values the wrong database accent are corrected and well displayed by the server.

But each case can be different.