# PDO UTF-8 encoding issue?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

i am using PDO for connecting to MYSQL database

all tables in database have **utf8_unicode_ci** Collation

**here is my connection code :**

```
<?php
$mysql_username = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_database = "cms";

try
{
    //connect
    global $db;
    $db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $mysql_database . ';host=' . $mysql_host . ';charset=utf8;', $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
    die("Unable Connect To DataBase");
}
?>
```

in localhost i have no problem with encoding but when i uploaded the source to a host i see **??????** instead of characters?

Answer (score 27):

This:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
```

is entirely pointless. See http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php. The `MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND` is executed right after the connection is established, no later. If you set this on an already fully created PDO object, it's too late and it never executes. You need to pass it to the constructor:

```
new PDO(..., ..., ..., array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'))
```

Alternatively, if your PHP version supports it, add `charset=utf8` to the DSN.

Comment: i did that but still no effect

Comment: Is everything else properly set up? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Also jump to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854446/save-accents-in-mysql-database-php

Comment: Worked great on CentOS 6, MySQL 5.1. Saved me some lookup time, thanks! IMHO this should be accepted as the correct answer, I had the same ??????? for Kanji, did this, worked. Done.

Comment: It worked! This method removes my error on Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS), Mysql 5.5.54. Really, thank you.