# Mysql Diacritic/Accent Insensitive search and storage

Tags: mysql, utf-8, pdo, character-encoding, diacritics

I am having frustrating times with performing Diacritic/accent insensitive searches of my database.

I have a table with alternative language terms stored in it. I have ensured that it has been set to use **`utf8`** and collated in **`utf8_general_ci`** (I have also tried `_bin` and `_unicode_ci`).

The trouble is that:

- Search for `Hahnchen` when `Hähnchen` is stored it **will** yield a result
- Search for `Hähnchen` when `Hähnchen` is stored **will not** yield a result

If I work in phpmyadmin I can save values as above:

```
Hähnchen
```

But, working from my scripts this gets converted to:

```
HÃ¼hnchen
```

- Search for `Hahnchen` when `HÃ¼hnchen` is stored it **will not** yield a result
- Search for `Hähnchen` when `HÃ¼hnchen` is stored **will** yield a result

Is there anything I am missing? I've read dozens of similar posts with no definitive answer (everything I have tried has failed).

Answer (score 0):

[Useful post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496557/pdo-utf-8-encoding-issue)

After reading the above linked post, in particular the answer from 'deceze' it appears that he is correct in stating that:

```
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8');
```

Is a nonsense (in some instances). I ended up adding the option explicitly in the connection parameters.

Solution eg:

```
    mysql:host=localhost;charset=utf8;dbname=.....
```

This resolves the search issue and the garbled data saving issue.

:)