# json_encode (mysql database|table charset utf8)

Tags: php, json, utf-8, character-encoding

In my code `json_encode($result)` isn't working but if I `print_r($result)` it will output. Now I know this is simply a charset encoding problem and I know the many different ways in php to convert the output to UTF8, but my question is more related to why my output is not UTF8 to begin with when both my database and table are UTF8?

```
function conn(){
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classicmodels';
    $username = '*******';
    $password = '*******';
    $options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
    return $db;
 }

$db = conn();
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($result) //outputs fine
//echo json_encode($result);
```

The `print_r($result)` output looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 103
            [customerName] => Atelier graphique
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 112
            [customerName] => Signal Gift Stores
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 114
            [customerName] => Australian Collectors, Co.
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 119
            [customerName] => La Rochelle Gifts
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 121
            [customerName] => Baane Mini Imports
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 124
            [customerName] => Mini Gifts Distributors Ltd.
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 125
            [customerName] => Havel & Zbyszek Co
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 128
            [customerName] => Blauer See Auto, Co.
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 129
            [customerName] => Mini Wheels Co.
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 131
            [customerName] => Land of Toys Inc.
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 141
            [customerName] => Euro+ Shopping Channel
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 144
            [customerName] => Volvo Model Replicas, Co
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 145
            [customerName] => Danish Wholesale Imports
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 146
            [customerName] => Saveley & Henriot, Co.
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 148
            [customerName] => Dragon Souveniers, Ltd.
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 151
            [customerName] => Muscle Machine Inc
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 157
            [customerName] => Diecast Classics Inc.
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 161
            [customerName] => Technics Stores Inc.
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 166
            [customerName] => Handji Gifts& Co
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 167
            [customerName] => Herkku Gifts
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 168
            [customerName] => American Souvenirs Inc
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 169
            [customerName] => Porto Imports Co.
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 171
            [customerName] => Daedalus Designs Imports
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 172
            [customerName] => La Corne D'abondance, Co.
        )

    [24] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 173
            [customerName] => Cambridge Collectables Co.
        )

    [25] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 175
            [customerName] => Gift Depot Inc.
        )

    [26] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 177
            [customerName] => Osaka Souveniers Co.
        )

    [27] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 181
            [customerName] => Vitachrome Inc.
        )

    [28] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 186
            [customerName] => Toys of Finland, Co.
        )

    [29] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 187
            [customerName] => AV Stores, Co.
        )

    [30] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 189
            [customerName] => Clover Collections, Co.
        )

    [31] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 198
            [customerName] => Auto-Moto Classics Inc.
        )

    [32] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 201
            [customerName] => UK Collectables, Ltd.
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 202
            [customerName] => Canadian Gift Exchange Network
        )

    [34] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 204
            [customerName] => Online Mini Collectables
        )

    [35] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 205
            [customerName] => Toys4GrownUps.com
        )

    [36] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 206
            [customerName] => Asian Shopping Network, Co
        )

    [37] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 209
            [customerName] => Mini Caravy
        )

    [38] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 211
            [customerName] => King Kong Collectables, Co.
        )

    [39] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 216
            [customerName] => Enaco Distributors
        )

    [40] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 219
            [customerName] => Boards & Toys Co.
        )

    [41] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 223
            [customerName] => Nat�rlich Autos
        )

    [42] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 227
            [customerName] => Heintze Collectables
        )

    [43] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 233
            [customerName] => Qu�bec Home Shopping Network
        )

    [44] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 237
            [customerName] => ANG Resellers
        )

    [45] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 239
            [customerName] => Collectable Mini Designs Co.
        )

    [46] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 240
            [customerName] => giftsbymail.co.uk
        )

    [47] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 242
            [customerName] => Alpha Cognac
        )

    [48] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 247
            [customerName] => Messner Shopping Network
        )

    [49] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 249
            [customerName] => Amica Models & Co.
        )

    [50] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 250
            [customerName] => Lyon Souveniers
        )

    [51] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 256
            [customerName] => Auto Associ�s & Cie.
        )

    [52] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 259
            [customerName] => Toms Spezialit�ten, Ltd
        )

    [53] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 260
            [customerName] => Royal Canadian Collectables, Ltd.
        )

    [54] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 273
            [customerName] => Franken Gifts, Co
        )

    [55] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 276
            [customerName] => Anna's Decorations, Ltd
        )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 278
            [customerName] => Rovelli Gifts
        )

    [57] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 282
            [customerName] => Souveniers And Things Co.
        )

    [58] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 286
            [customerName] => Marta's Replicas Co.
        )

    [59] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 293
            [customerName] => BG&E Collectables
        )

    [60] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 298
            [customerName] => Vida Sport, Ltd
        )

    [61] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 299
            [customerName] => Norway Gifts By Mail, Co.
        )

    [62] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 303
            [customerName] => Schuyler Imports
        )

    [63] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 307
            [customerName] => Der Hund Imports
        )

    [64] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 311
            [customerName] => Oulu Toy Supplies, Inc.
        )

    [65] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 314
            [customerName] => Petit Auto
        )

    [66] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 319
            [customerName] => Mini Classics
        )

    [67] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 320
            [customerName] => Mini Creations Ltd.
        )

    [68] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 321
            [customerName] => Corporate Gift Ideas Co.
        )

    [69] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 323
            [customerName] => Down Under Souveniers, Inc
        )

    [70] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 324
            [customerName] => Stylish Desk Decors, Co.
        )

    [71] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 328
            [customerName] => Tekni Collectables Inc.
        )

    [72] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 333
            [customerName] => Australian Gift Network, Co
        )

    [73] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 334
            [customerName] => Suominen Souveniers
        )

    [74] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 335
            [customerName] => Cramer Spezialit�ten, Ltd
        )

    [75] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 339
            [customerName] => Classic Gift Ideas, Inc
        )

    [76] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 344
            [customerName] => CAF Imports
        )

    [77] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 347
            [customerName] => Men 'R' US Retailers, Ltd.
        )

    [78] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 348
            [customerName] => Asian Treasures, Inc.
        )

    [79] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 350
            [customerName] => Marseille Mini Autos
        )

    [80] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 353
            [customerName] => Reims Collectables
        )

    [81] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 356
            [customerName] => SAR Distributors, Co
        )

    [82] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 357
            [customerName] => GiftsForHim.com
        )

    [83] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 361
            [customerName] => Kommission Auto
        )

    [84] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 362
            [customerName] => Gifts4AllAges.com
        )

    [85] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 363
            [customerName] => Online Diecast Creations Co.
        )

    [86] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 369
            [customerName] => Lisboa Souveniers, Inc
        )

    [87] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 376
            [customerName] => Precious Collectables
        )

    [88] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 379
            [customerName] => Collectables For Less Inc.
        )

    [89] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 381
            [customerName] => Royale Belge
        )

    [90] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 382
            [customerName] => Salzburg Collectables
        )

    [91] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 385
            [customerName] => Cruz & Sons Co.
        )

    [92] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 386
            [customerName] => L'ordine Souveniers
        )

    [93] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 398
            [customerName] => Tokyo Collectables, Ltd
        )

    [94] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 406
            [customerName] => Auto Canal+ Petit
        )

    [95] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 409
            [customerName] => Stuttgart Collectable Exchange
        )

    [96] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 412
            [customerName] => Extreme Desk Decorations, Ltd
        )

    [97] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 415
            [customerName] => Bavarian Collectables Imports, Co.
        )

    [98] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 424
            [customerName] => Classic Legends Inc.
        )

    [99] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 443
            [customerName] => Feuer Online Stores, Inc
        )

    [100] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 447
            [customerName] => Gift Ideas Corp.
        )

    [101] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 448
            [customerName] => Scandinavian Gift Ideas
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 450
            [customerName] => The Sharp Gifts Warehouse
        )

    [103] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 452
            [customerName] => Mini Auto Werke
        )

    [104] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 455
            [customerName] => Super Scale Inc.
        )

    [105] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 456
            [customerName] => Microscale Inc.
        )

    [106] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 458
            [customerName] => Corrida Auto Replicas, Ltd
        )

    [107] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 459
            [customerName] => Warburg Exchange
        )

    [108] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 462
            [customerName] => FunGiftIdeas.com
        )

    [109] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 465
            [customerName] => Anton Designs, Ltd.
        )

    [110] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 471
            [customerName] => Australian Collectables, Ltd
        )

    [111] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 473
            [customerName] => Frau da Collezione
        )

    [112] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 475
            [customerName] => West Coast Collectables Co.
        )

    [113] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 477
            [customerName] => Mit Vergn�gen & Co.
        )

    [114] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 480
            [customerName] => Kremlin Collectables, Co.
        )

    [115] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 481
            [customerName] => Raanan Stores, Inc
        )

    [116] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 484
            [customerName] => Iberia Gift Imports, Corp.
        )

    [117] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 486
            [customerName] => Motor Mint Distributors Inc.
        )

    [118] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 487
            [customerName] => Signal Collectibles Ltd.
        )

    [119] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 489
            [customerName] => Double Decker Gift Stores, Ltd
        )

    [120] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 495
            [customerName] => Diecast Collectables
        )

    [121] => Array
        (
            [customerNumber] => 496
            [customerName] => Kelly's Gift Shop
        )

)
```

**Question:** If both my db/table are UTF8 why does my output from the database in php not already in UTF8 format?

Comment: Including db/table your page must be in  `UTF8`!!

Comment: @Saty my page? as in the PHP page?

Comment: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');` add this to your page and check

Comment: @Saty still doesn't work, it shouldn't be a header problem though since it's `json_encode` which is whats failing which is before it outputs it back over the wire.

Comment: The encoding with which your data is retrieved from the database depends on the ***connection encoding*** (implicitly) defined when you connect to your database. MySQL converts data on the fly to that encoding. Also see [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @deceze good to know that it does depend on the connection encoding, but I already have that in my connection `$db->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND,'SET NAMES UTF8');` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: → http://stackoverflow.com/a/18496873/476

Comment: @deceze I've tried it that way to.

Comment: @deceze I'm running PHP(5.5.33)

Comment: Then a) give full details on the database connection establishment and b) a sample of the string you expect and a sample of how it's actually encoded with `echo bin2hex($str)`.

Comment: `bin2hex` sample of a non-ASCII string please...?

Comment: @deceze it's not a string its an array, so you want me loop through the array and `bin2hex` the values?

Comment: No, just pick one, show us what string you expect, and show us what its actual `bin2hex` value is.

Comment: @deceze I know it has to do with � in my output

Comment: @deceze I got it, I copied over connection options wrong, answer the question.

Answer (score -1):

`print_r(json_encode($result));` will work. `echo(json_encode($result));` will not work.Because it is a json array,arrays can not print by using **echo**

Comment: and i quote -"Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.
" http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I've `echo`'d json_encode many times works fine, the encoding function breaks because the charset of one of the array values isn't UTF8