# How to make PDO adapter run SET NAMES utf8 each time I connect?

Tags: php, mysql

```
abstract class RepositoryBase
{
    protected $connection;//This is PDO Object!

    public function __construct(PDO $connection = null)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
        if ($this->connection === null) {
            $this->connection = new PDO(
                'mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=project',
                'root',
                'usbw'
            );
            $this->connection->setAttribute(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
                PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
        }
    }
```

pdo set names utf8 <-- how can i do it

Comment: You'll find your answer in http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$options = [
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'"
];

$this->connection = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost:3307;dbname=project',
    'root',
    'usbw',
    $options
);

$this->connection->setAttribute(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,
    PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
);
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18496873/476. Not to mention that the syntax for the `setAttribute` call is complete nonsense.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')' in I:\Project\root\Repositories\RepositoryBase.php on line 23

Comment: Sorry, I just get from my configs and not validated for this scenario.

Comment: Fixed and tested example. For me works fine.