# How do I insert special characters into SQL from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I want to store Spanish characters in SQL (á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡).

Consider the following query:

```
INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES('áéíóú')
```

When I run the query in phpMyAdmin the characters are stored correctly.

However, when I run the query from my php code they are stored as Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³Ãº

Here is the relevant code:

```
<?php
...
$query = "INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES('áéíóú')";
?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854446/save-accents-in-mysql-database I believe this is what you're looking for?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: See discussions of "Mojibake" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored .